# Disabling NetBIOS for Samba SMB2

Tags: samba, server-message-block, netbios, smb-conf

I need to get a pcap for SMB2, but without using NetBIOS as a transport (Direct TCP connection).

I did disable netbios on server and client. Both sides on Linux.

```
[global]
...
   min protocol = SMB3
   protocol = SMB3
   disable netbios = yes
```

When I try to mount share, I run a wireshark and I still get SMB2 packages via NetBIOS.

I didn't find anything about disabling netbios in `man smbclient` and `man mount.cifs`.

What can I do to get what I need?

Comment: 'min protocol' is a synonym for 'server min protocol', 'protocol' is a synonym for 'server max protocol', there are a couple of others 'client min protocol' & 'client max protocol'. Unless you are using an extremely old version of Samba, both the 'max' protocols default to 'SMB3', so you do not need to set these. Try setting 'server min protocol = SMB3' & 'client min protocol = SMB3'.